# How to display in a form/tree view a computed field with store = False ?Odoo 11

Tags: odoo-11

In Odoo 11, How to display in a form/tree view a computed field with store = False ?

For example :

The field Marge is a computed field with store=False

> margin_pct = fields.Char(string = 'Marge', compute =
>   _getmarginpct)

When the view is in modify mode the value of the field marge is displayed and modified as well

[modify image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM0FM.png)

But when the view is in save mode or when we come back on the view the value of the field marge is not displayed

[save image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpJlX.png)

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be modifying the value of **margin_pct** field in an onchange function. Since this field is read only the values modified by on change functions will not be saved. So use depends instead of onchange and it should work.